# Prove that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{2n+1})^{3n} = \frac1{e\sqrt{e}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

I have this problem that I cannot seem to solve. I tried splitting it into two factors $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{2n+1})^{2n}\times 
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (1-\frac{1}{2n+1})^{n}$$ but that did not help because of the $+1$ in the denominator. So I tried multiplying both powers by $\frac{2n+1}{2n+1}$ but that did not help either. So now I'm stuck,and don't know what to do
can someone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**: write $3n = \dfrac{3}{2}(2n+1) - \dfrac{3}{2}$, and use the fact that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1-\dfrac{1}{2n+1}\right)^{2n+1} = \dfrac{1}{e}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: that was perfect, thanks! so how did you figure out that you must write 3n as $\dfrac{3}{2}(2n+1) - \dfrac{3}{2}$

Comment: You need the "$2n+1$" in place so you have to find "p" and "q" such that: $3n=p(2n+1) + q$

Answer (score 4):

Let $\frac{1}{2n+1}=-t\implies t\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^{3n}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\left(1+t\right)^{-\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac 1t+1\right)}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\left(1+t\right)^{\frac 1t}\right)^{-\frac 32}\cdot \lim_{t\to 0}\left(1+t\right)^{-\frac 32}$$
$$=\left(e\right)^{-\frac 32}\cdot 1$$
$$=e^{-3/2}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{e\sqrt e}}$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Write as $$\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^{3n} = \left(\left(1-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^{2n+1} \right)^{3/2} \left(1-\frac{1}{2n+1}\right)^{-3/2}$$

Comment: Thank you so much. But what process did you go through to find out to put 3n in the form $\frac32(2n+1)-\frac32$?

Answer (score 3):

Another way to solve the problem.

Consider $$A_n=(1-\frac{1}{2n+1})^{3n}$$ Take logarithms $$\log(A_n)=3n \log(1-\frac{1}{2n+1})$$ Now, remember that, for small $x$ $$\log(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Replace $x$ by $\frac{1}{2n+1}$ which make $$\log(A_n)=-3n\Big(\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac 12\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}+\cdots\Big)$$ Now, long division $$\log(A_n)=-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{3}{8 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ $$A_n\approx e^{-3/2}(1+\frac 3 {8n})$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

Comment: Always good to see slightly off-beat answers. +1

Comment: That's not off beat. If you know the series for $\ln(1\pm x)$, this is the natural thing to do.